# How to compute the normal vector for a metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors

So say I have a bubble embedded in a spacetime with metric:
$$ ds^2 = -dt^2 + a(t) ( dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2_2) $$

how do I compute the normal vector if I assume the wall of the bubble the metric represents follows a time-like trajectory, for any $a(t)$?

Since we are interested in dynamical solutions, we let the positions on the brane be $(t,r, \theta, \phi) \rightarrow (T(\tau), R(\tau), \theta, \phi)$.

In equation (3.4) of [arXiv:hep-ph/0003173](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0003173)<sup>1</sup> they have computed the norm for the brane in a similar fashion but for a different metric. They had $ds^2 = -u(r) dt^2 + \frac{1}{u(r)}dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega_3^2$ and got $N_a = (-\dot{R}, \dot{T},0,0,0)$ so I also expect to have a $\dot{T}$ in my normal.

---

<sup>1</sup> H. Collins and B. Holdom, "Brane cosmologies without orbifolds", [*Phys. Rev. D* **62**, 105009 (2000)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.62.105009).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a hypersurface $\Sigma$ parameterized by $x^\mu(y)$ where $y^a$ is some set of intrinsic coordinates on $\Sigma$, then the tangent vectors on $\Sigma$ are given by $e_a^\mu = \partial_{y^a} x^\mu$. A normal vector then satisfies $t \cdot e_a = 0$.

Alternatively, if you know that your hypersurface is described by $f(x)=0$, then the normal vector $t_\mu \propto \partial_\mu f$.

The first method is more suited to your setup. You have a $\Sigma$ parameterized in terms of $(\tau,\theta,\phi)$ so you can work out the tangent vectors as
$$
e_1^\mu = \partial_\tau x^\mu = ({\dot T} , {\dot R} , 0 , 0 ) , \qquad e_2^\mu = \partial_\theta x^\mu = (0,0,1,0) , \qquad e_3^\mu = \partial_\phi x^\mu = (0,0,0,1). 
$$
The normal vector is tangent to all of these vectors above. Writing $t_\mu = (t_0,t_1,t_2,t_3)$ and setting $t_\mu e^\mu_a = 0$, we find
$$
t_2 = t_3 = 0 , \qquad t_0 {\dot T} + t_1 {\dot R} = 0 \quad \implies \quad t_0 = - \lambda {\dot R} , \qquad t_1 = \lambda {\dot T} .
$$
The normal vector is then
$$
t_\mu = \lambda ( - {\dot R} , {\dot T} , 0 , 0 ).
$$
The proportionality constant $\lambda$ is determined by requiring that $t$ is unit normalized: $t^\mu t_\mu = - 1$. Explicitly  [using the metric $ds^2 = -dt^2 + a(t)( dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega_2^2 )]$,
$$
t^\mu t_\mu = - ( t_0 )^2 + \frac{1}{a} (t_1)^2 = - \lambda^2 {\dot R}^2 + \frac{1}{a} \lambda^2 {\dot T}^2 = - 1 \quad \implies \quad \lambda = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ {\dot R}^2 + a^{-1} {\dot T}^2 } }.
$$
Thus, the unit normal is
$$
t_\mu = \frac{( - {\dot R} , {\dot T} , 0 , 0 )}{\sqrt{ {\dot R}^2 + a^{-1} {\dot T}^2 } }
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is you want to calculate the unit vector normal to the surface of a bubble if the embedding of the bubble wall in spacetime is described by a condition like $f(r,t) = r - R(t) = 0$, with $a\,\dot{R} < 1$. Is that correct?

If so, you take the (four-dimensional) gradient of the function $f(r,t)$ that describes the embedding of the bubble wall in spacetime and then normalize it.
$$ \partial_{\mu} f(r,t) = \delta_{\mu}{}^{r} - \dot{R}\,\delta_{\mu}{}^{t}$$
$$ g^{\mu\nu}\,\partial_{\mu} f \,\partial_{\nu} f = \frac{1}{a^2}-\dot{R}^2 = \frac{1-a^2 \dot{R}^2}{a^2}$$
$$ n_{\mu} = \frac{\partial_{\mu}f}{\sqrt{g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\alpha} f \partial_{\beta} f}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2 \dot{R}^2}}\left(\delta_{\mu}{}^{r} - \dot{R}\,\delta_{\mu}{}^{t}\right)$$
$$ n^{\mu} = g^{\mu\nu} n_{\nu} = \frac{1}{a \sqrt{1-a^2 \dot{R}^2}}\left(\delta_{\mu}{}^{r} +a^{2} \dot{R}\,\delta_{\mu}{}^{t}\right) $$

Comment: Thanks for this! May I ask how you got the function $f(r,t)$? While this makes much sense, I expect to have a $\dot{T}$ somewhere in there. I updated my question with the reason why. What do you think about that?